# ArcGIS Pro will not display symbols on map

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

Using ArcGIS Pro with an imported data file of state plane UTMS.  The file imports nicely, but I can not get symbols to display.  I have applied simple black circle symbols, but they do not display.  If I select a point in the attribute table, the selection will show on the map.  If a apply labels, they are displayed correctly.  If I change the symbol size, the symbols still do not display, but the labels will shift to account for the change in the symbol size.

Comment: What happens if you zoom to layer?  What if you select a few records and zoom to selected features?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have transparency set to 100% for that layer.  Select the layer in the contents pane.  Select the Feature Layer tab.  Set Transparency to 0%.

[image]

[image]